# Ellipse detection with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to detect ellipses with OpenCV for Android, using the Tutorial 2-Basic included with OpenCV 2.4.1 package as a starting point. Note that my ellipse would be a perfect-photoshop one.

From what I understand, using the "HoughCircles" will only find perfect (or so) circles, thus leaving ellipses out.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am a total beginner at OpenCV

This is what I've tried so far

```
    case Sample2NativeCamera.VIEW_MODE_CANNY: (ignore the Canny mode...)

        capture.retrieve(mGray, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_GREY_FRAME);
        Imgproc.HoughCircles(mGray, mCircles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20);
        Log.d("Ellipse Points", " X " + mCircles.get(1,1)[0] + mCircles.get(1, 1)[1]);

        break;
```

If you think any more info could be useful, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem is similar to this thread [Detection of coins (and fit ellipses) on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4785419/1085483) .

You should take a look a opencv's function [fitEllipse](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitellipse#fitellipse).

Answer (score 5):

The parameters used in `HoughCircles` play a fundamental role. `HoughCircles` will detect not just perfect, but also near-perfect circles (ellipses). I suggest you check this examples:

- [How to detect circles (coins) in a photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044119/opencv-cvfindcontours-how-do-i-separate-components-of-a-contour/6931135#6931135)
- [Simple object detection using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416361/176769)
- [OpenCV dot target detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416428/176769)
- [Reshaping noisy coin into a circle form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10313602/176769)

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738792/tutorial-for-iphone-opencv-on-shape-recognising/5739247#5739247) has a decent collection of references.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have an idea of the sizes of the ellipses that you're looking for, then try the following steps:

- Find Canny edges in the image
- Use a sliding window, the size of which is the maximum length of the major axis of ellipses you're looking for.
- Within the window, collect all edge pixels, pick 6 pixels randomly and use [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29) to fit an ellipse in the [general form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections).
- Repeat the above step in a RANSAC like procedure.
- If there are enough inliers, you have an ellipse.