# Find straight lines in contour openCV

Tags: android, opencv, contour

I'm using android openCV and I want to detect triangle, rectangle and circle in an image. So I do it as follow: Canny => findContours => approxPolyDP and get this image:
[image: Image Hosted by ImageShack.us]

However, the result of approxPolyDP contains so many vertices so I can't determine which shape is it. To eliminate the vertices, I want to detect lines in each contours and find their intersections. How can I do that for a single contour?

Comment: do the red circles also count as circles? I am asking this coz they have open contours that's why and hence ideally don't qualify as circles...

Comment: The "red circles" are actually the C letter :), I draw it using Core.putText, we don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For circles detection, use [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cvhoughcircles#houghcircles).

Then here you are just looking for simplified polygons (triangles and squares). Have you tried  tweaking epsilon in approxPolyDP?

Here is an example snippet from the openCV [squares.cpp sample code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) - see how approximation accuracy (epsilon, the third parameter of approxPolyDP), is set relative to the size of the contour.

C++ code, but the openCV interface should be the same, so I'm sure it's straightforward to adapt to your environment.

```
 // test each contour
  for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
      {
          // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
          // to the contour perimeter
      approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, 
                        arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

          // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
          // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
          // and be convex.
          // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
          // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
          // contour orientation
      if( approx.size() == 4 &&
         fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
         isContourConvex(Mat(approx)) )
          {
          double maxCosine = 0;

          for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
              {
                  // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
              double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
              maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
              }

              // if cosines of all angles are small
              // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
              // vertices to resultant sequence

          if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
              squares.push_back(approx);
          }
      }
```

Comment: There are better ways to detect circles than to use HoughCircles. Check these http://stackoverflow.com/q/4785419/1085483 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10982988/1085483