# Automatically detect and crop ROI in OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have these images to compare with each other. However, there are too many blacks that I think I can crop out to make comparison more effective.

[image: Mars 1]
[image: Mars 2]
[image: Mars 3]

What I want to do is crop Mars. Rectangle or round whichever may yield better results when compared. I was worrying that if the cropping would result to images of different sizes, comparison wouldn't work out as well as expected? Ideas how to do it and sample codes if possible? Thanks in advance

UPDATE: Tried using cvHoughCircles() it won't detect the planet :/

Comment: When did you take these pictures? Mars is pretty deep in the sunset right now since it's about to go into Solar Conjunction.

Comment: Threshold, [detect connected component][1], crop image. Done.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044119/opencv-cvfindcontours-how-do-i-separate-components-of-a-contour

Answer (score 6):

Try to use color detection. You need to find all the colors except black. [Here](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-opencv/) and [here](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ru/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html) are nice explanations of this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert these images to gray scale images using `cvCvtColor(img,imgGrayScale,CV_BGR2GRAY)`

Then threshold them using `cvThreshold(imgGrayScale,imgThresh,x,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY)`. Here, you have to find a good value for x(I think x=50 is ok).

```
CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
cvMoments(imgThresh, moments, 1);
double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);
int x = moment10/area;
int y = moment01/area;
```

Now you know the (x.y) coordinate of the blob. Then you can crop the image using `cvSetImageROI(imgThresh, cvRect(x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10))`. Here I have assumed that the radius of this blob is less than 10 pixel.

All cropped images are of same size and the white blob (planet) is exactly at the middle of the image.

Then you can compare images using normalized cross-correlation.

Comment: Hi! The ROI idea was great. Will you help me set my bounded box as my ROI? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: It is easy to set ROI using `cvSetImageROI` function. But you can use 1 ROI for single image.

Answer (score 1):

There's no fundamental reason why a histogram would fail here. I would convert the image to greyscale before doing a histogram, just to make the numbers more manageable. A color image has a 3D histogram; the Red, Green, Blue and Greyscale histograms are all 1D projections of that 3D histogram.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have included unnecessary info. What I wanted to do was to compare without the blacks.